# xamarin.android X509Certificate2 constructor/import failed with SecureString password instead of plain string

Tags: android, xamarin, certificate, x509certificate2, securestring

I have a self signed certificate with private key in a PFX file. It is added as resource in a `Xamarin.Android` c# application in Visual Studio 2015. I'm using it as client certificate to establish secure HTTPS connection to a Web service.

To do this I import the certificate in a `X509Certificate2` object. When I supply the password for the certificate's private key as a plain text (string) it works well, but I would like to use the `X509Certificate2` constructors/import methods which use `SecureString`.

Unfortunately they throw

> 'Unable to decode certificate exception'

in that case, no matter if constructor or import method is used, no matter if the certificate is passed as byte[] or file name.

My question is why it fails with the password in a `SecureString` while works well with plain string and how to proceed in order to use `SecureString` for the password.

Thanks!

Georgi

Just to add that the same code with same certificate file and password works well under Windows 10, .NET 4
Otherwise Xamarin.Android is 6.1.1.1 and Xamarin extension is 4.1.1.3, minimum android to target is API level 19, tested on Android 6.0

Comment: Just to add that the same code with same certificate file and password works well under Windows 10, .NET 4
Otherwise Xamarin.Android is 6.1.1.1 and Xamarin extension is 4.1.1.3, minimum android to target is API level 19, tested on Android 6.0

Georgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `SecureString` is not completely supported in Mono. See the [source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs#L233) for a comment. It calls the certificate class' `Import` method and passes a `(string)null`:

```
[MonoTODO ("SecureString is incomplete")]
public override void Import (byte[] rawData, SecureString password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
{
    Import (rawData, (string) null, keyStorageFlags);
}
```

Also note that `SecureString` does not make your data 100% [secure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#HowSecure):

> Overall, SecureString is more secure than String because it limits the
>   exposure of sensitive string data. However, those *strings may still be
>   exposed to any process or operation that has access to raw memory*,
>   such as a malicious process running on the host computer, a process
>   dump, or a user-viewable swap file. Instead of using SecureString to
>   protect passwords, the recommended alternative is to use an opaque
>   handle to credentials that are stored outside of the process.

Comment: Thank you, Krumelur, all is clear. Anyway they should throw some other kind of exception in that case like 'Not implemented' for example.

Cheers!

Comment: Submit a pull request with the change ;-)